Error: Number of pixels in mask does not match predictions size in Python/Rasterio workflow
I have implemented a random forest model using scikit-learn and Rasterio in Python to predict pixel values within a shapefile containing multiple polygons. However, I'm encountering an error:ValueError: Number of pixels in mask does not match number of predictions.Here's a simplified version of my script:
# Function to extract pixel values within a polygon
def extract_pixels(src, polygon, nodata):
    out_image, out_transform = mask(src, [polygon], crop=True, nodata=nodata)
    out_image = out_image.transpose((1, 2, 0))  # Transpose to have dimensions (rows, cols, bands)
    return out_image, out_transform

# Function to mask nodata values in a raster
def mask_nodata(arr, nodata):
    return arr != nodata

# Load the model
model_path = r'D:\SNAP_data\Models\random_forest_vv_vhband_only_acc092.joblib'
clf = joblib.load(model_path)

# Load the shapefile with polygons
shapefile_path = r'C:\SNAP\Random_forest\test\clip.shp'
shapefile = gpd.read_file(shapefile_path)

# Load the TIFF file
tif_path_input = r'D:\SNAP_data\S1_imagery\Processing\Final_processing\S1A_20220108_11x11x3x3.tif'
tif_path_output = r'C:\SNAP\Random_forest\test\class\rf_band_only_polygon.tif'

# Start timing
start_time = time.time()
with rasterio.open(tif_path_input) as src:
    image = src.read()
    profile = src.profile
    transform = src.transform
    nodata = src.nodata  # Get nodata value from the raster

    # Initialize an empty array for the predicted results
    predictions = np.zeros(image.shape[1:], dtype=np.uint8)

    # Iterate over each polygon in the shapefile
    for idx, row in shapefile.iterrows():
        polygon = row['geometry']
        
        # Extract pixel values within the polygon
        pixels, _ = extract_pixels(src, polygon, nodata)
        
        # Mask nodata values
        valid_mask = mask_nodata(pixels, nodata)  # Create a mask for non-nodata values
        pixels = pixels[valid_mask.all(axis=2)]  # Apply mask across all bands
        
        # Check size of pixels after masking nodata
        assert pixels.size > 0, "No valid pixels found within the polygon after masking nodata."
        
        # Print shape and size of pixels
        print(f"Pixels shape: {pixels.shape}")
        print(f"Pixels size: {pixels.size}")
        print(f"Pixels dim: {pixels.ndim}")
        
        # Reshape pixels if necessary
        if pixels.ndim == 3:
            n_rows, n_cols, n_bands = pixels.shape
            pixels = pixels.reshape(-1, n_bands)  # Flatten to (num_samples, num_bands)
        elif pixels.ndim == 2:
            n_samples, n_bands = pixels.shape
            pixels = pixels.reshape(n_samples, n_bands)
        else:
            raise ValueError("Unexpected dimensions in pixels.")
        
        # Check size of pixels after reshaping
        assert pixels.size == n_samples * n_bands, "Pixels not reshaped correctly."
        
        # Predict using the Random Forest model
        preds = clf.predict(pixels)
        
        # Print shape and size of preds
        print(f"Preds shape: {preds.shape}")
        print(f"Preds size: {preds.size}")
        
        # Check size of preds
        assert preds.size == pixels.shape[0], "Number of predictions does not match number of pixels."
        
        # Reshape the predictions back to the original polygon shape
        preds = preds.reshape(pixels.shape[0])
        
        # Create a mask for the current polygon
        polygon_mask = geometry_mask([polygon], transform=transform, invert=True, out_shape=image.shape[1:])
        
        # Handle nodata in the polygon mask for all bands
        nodata_mask = np.all(image != nodata, axis=0)  # Create a mask considering all bands
        polygon_mask = polygon_mask & nodata_mask
    
        # Ensure polygon_mask is boolean type
        polygon_mask = polygon_mask.astype(bool)
        
        # Debug: Print the sum and shape of the mask
        print('Polygon mask sum:', polygon_mask.sum())
        print('Polygon mask shape:', polygon_mask.shape)
    
        # Check if predictions and polygon_mask have the same number of True values
        if polygon_mask.sum() != preds.size:
            print("Number of pixels in mask does not match number of predictions. Check alignment and nodata handling.")
            print(f"polygon_mask.sum() = {polygon_mask.sum()}, preds.size = {preds.size}")
            # continue
    
        # Combine the mask with the existing predictions array
        predictions[polygon_mask] = preds.flatten()

Error:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[49], line 109
    105     print(f"polygon_mask.sum() = {polygon_mask.sum()}, preds.size = {preds.size}")
    106     # continue
    107 
    108 # Combine the mask with the existing predictions array
--> 109 predictions[polygon_mask] = preds.flatten()
    111 # Debug: Visualize the polygon mask and predictions
    112 plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))

ValueError: 
NumPy boolean array indexing assignment cannot assign 2956956 input values to the 2698935 output values where the mask is true


It helps if you post the full traceback when trying to get help with an error

@mikewatt: I added the full trackback as requested.
